# How can I run `pod install` ignoring private source repos?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I started working in an existing iOS app. The app was developed by another company and the `Podfile` of the app contains a reference to a private repo of that company. I want to add a new pod, but when I run `pod install` I get the following error:

```
Cloning spec repo `some-private-repo` from `https://some-private-repo`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://some-private-repo` named `some-private-repo`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

How can I add a single new pod without cloning the private repo?

Comment: If you don't have the private repo and there are references of the code inside your app, how are you supposed to get your app worked? Is it because they committed/gave the pods too?

Comment: The Pods directory is commited. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control, one of the benefits is that after cloning the repo, the project can immediately build and run.

Comment: Indeed, but you can't build if you don't have access indeed. You could fake a podspec and use a local path to do so, but I'm wondering what's gonna happen in that case of where you point into the `Pods` folder itself. Is the company repo containing only Swift/Objective-C Files? Not framework.static lib?

Comment: @rubenlop88 Copy private pods available in your code to `~/.cocoapods/repos` location

Answer (score 0):

In Given code, they commited all pods also. So in your repository already pods exists. First of all remove all pods from repository. And then install all pods.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I don't understand. And I'm new to iOS development too. What do you mean by "remove all pods from repository"?